# Language with both passive and antipassive constructions

Tags: passive, antipassive, split-ergative

Are there languages with both passive and anti-passive constructions (that are well documented) but not necessarily have split alignment?

In other words, are there nominative-accusative languages with antipassive constructions, or ergative-absolutive languages with passive constructions?

Comment: What about split-ergative languages?

Comment: Yeah I initially thought those might be offered as answers, but I'd like to see if there are languages that are not split-ergative but have both passive and antipassive.

Comment: @Noble_Bright_Life it's been argued that all ergative languages are to some extent split, so unless you want to restrict this entirely to nominative-accusative languages there's likely to be borderline cases that aren't clear-cut ergative vs split-ergative

Comment: @Tristan: I'm more interested in languages possessing both constructions and not necessarily their syntactic alignment, so being ergative-absolutive is no issue, as long as it can be shown the language has both construction.